# Populate tableview with Firebase realtime database

Tags: json, swift, firebase-realtime-database

Currently I get data from json file located on http server

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "https://test.com/test") {
                do {
                    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    jsonData = try decoder.decode(TestList.self, from: data)
                } catch {
                    print("error:\(error)")
                }

struct  TestList: Decodable {
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case items
        }
        let items: [Item]
    }

struct Item: Decodable {
            var item_type: String?
            //...
            enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case item_type
               //...
         }
            init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            self.item_type = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .mtype)
            //...        
            }
         }
```

Everything works fine but when
i switched to firebase realtime database and get the same json data

```
Database.database().reference().child("items").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
            guard let value = snapshot.value else { return }
            do {
                self.jsonData = try FirebaseDecoder().decode(TestList.self, from: value)
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        })
```

My JSON:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "item_type": "Rap",
      "1": "Kastro",
      "2": "EDI",
      "3": "Noble",
      "4": ""
    },
    {
      "item_type": "Rock",
      "1": "Nickelback",
      "2": "",
      "3": "",
      "4": ""
    },
    {
      "item_type": "Pop",
      "1": "Ringo",
      "2": "",
      "3": "",
      "4": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

got this message:

> typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary,
>   Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Not a
>   dictionary", underlyingError: nil))

How to fix this error ?

Comment: The Firebase real-time database does not work with JSON directly, however there's a great library that can help you with that: https://github.com/alickbass/CodableFirebase

Comment: I tried but its not working with Decodable

Comment: can you show the Json response you are getting. Because the response that you get is a dictionary and here testlist is an array.

Comment: Yeah but why its works when json file located on http server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this problem before, this is what I did to fix it. So let's say this is how my database looks like. Pay attention to the naming convention, in this example its snake case.

[image]

Let's say I want to create an array of users from this snapshot and populate my tableView. This is tricky cause the snapshot.value isn't really JSON and has a value of Any. This is probably why your app is crashing or in your case type is mismatch.

Lets create a model for our users. It will look something like this.

```
class User: Codable {
  var firstName: String
  var lastName: String
  var ageNumber: Int

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case firstName,lastName
    case ageNumber = "age"
  }
}
```

So let me point something our really fast. In my firebase database the user properties look like this 'first_name', 'age' 'last_name'. In my user model it look like this 'firstName', 'ageNumber' 'lastName'. So I had to add the coding keys because of the age not because of the first or last name. The first & last name changes by themselves when I set the keyCodingStrategy on my decoder.

This is how that code looks like. Left some comments to better explain what the code does.

```
var items = [Item]()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Use your database reference here.
    let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users")

    ref.observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        //First create a dict out of the snapshot value
        guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }

        //Create a decoder this is why I don't need to chage the first_name to firstName
        //inside my coding keys
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase

        //The key is the UID and the value is what we need to create a new users
        dict.forEach { (key, value) in
            do {
                //Create new user and add it to our users array
                //We convert the value to data for the decoder with this line of code
                let testListData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: value, options: .prettyPrinted)
                let testList = try decoder.decode(TestList.self, from: testListData)
                testList.items.forEach({ (item) in
                    self.items.append(item)
                })
            }
            catch let err {
            print(err.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
        //Reload Table View
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

**Edited**

So based on the JSON you provided. You will have to create your structs something like this.

```
struct TestList: Codable {
  var items: [Item]
}

struct Item: Codable {
  var itemType: String
  var one: String
  var two: String
  var three: String
  var four: String

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case itemType
    case one = "1"
    case two = "2"
    case three = "3"
    case four = "4"
  }
}
```

Hopefully this will solve your problem.

Comment: I added my Json to be more clear, can you help me ?

Comment: @Jay just updated the answer hopefully it helps. Let me know if it does.

Comment: I've changed  testList.items.forEach({ (item) in testList.items.append(item) }) otherwise items.append(item) says "Use of unresolved identifier 'items'" and guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return } executing else and return

Comment: Instead of items.append(item) you should be using the array you created to add the item.

Comment: let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "users") I've changed to let ref = Database.database().reference(withPath: "items") code compiles without errors but guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return } exits on return and code below not executing

Comment: I tried for child in snapshot.children { 
                let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
                let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
                print(dict) }                                                                                              gives:    ["3": Noble, "4": , "1": Kastro, "2": EDI, "item_type": Rap]
["3": , "4": , "1": Nickelback, "item_type": Rock, "2": ]
["3": , "4": , "1": Ringo, "2": , "item_type": Pop]

Comment: Try making one two three four optional strings in the Item struct.

Comment: var one: String?
      var two: String?
      var three: String?
      var four: String?

Comment: Nothing changed, guard let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return } exits on return and code below doesn't executes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208515/discussion-between-luis-ramirez-and-jay).